# Creating an Excel file on the fly and have it download/save on the client

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, export-to-excel, epplus

**Question**: What is an alternative to the last three lines of the following code in ASP.NET Core 1.1 and/or what are workarounds? On these last three lines `VS2015` is complaining `HttpResponse does not contain a definition for OutputStream, Flush(), End()`

**Background**: In my `ASP.NET Core 1.1` app I'm using [EPPlus.Core](https://github.com/VahidN/EPPlus.Core) to export data on the fly to Excel and have it downloaded/save on the client side. As a starter, I'm trying to mimic the following example (taken from [here](http://techbrij.com/export-excel-xls-xlsx-asp-net-npoi-epplus)), but `VS2015` is not recognizing the `last 3 lines` of this code.

```
public void ExportListUsingEPPlus()
{
    var data = new[]{
                        new{ Name="Ram", Email="ram@techbrij.com", Phone="111-222-3333" },
                        new{ Name="Shyam", Email="shyam@techbrij.com", Phone="159-222-1596" },
                        new{ Name="Mohan", Email="mohan@techbrij.com", Phone="456-222-4569" },
                        new{ Name="Sohan", Email="sohan@techbrij.com", Phone="789-456-3333" },
                        new{ Name="Karan", Email="karan@techbrij.com", Phone="111-222-1234" },
                        new{ Name="Brij", Email="brij@techbrij.com", Phone="111-222-3333" }
                };

    ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage();
    var workSheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
    workSheet.Cells[1, 1].LoadFromCollection(data, true);
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.Headers.Add("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=Contact.xlsx");
        excel.SaveAs(memoryStream);
        memoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Comment: You just keep asking the same question with different alternation (once it's csv, now is an excel file). If it can accept an `Stream` you can always do `new ExcelPackage(HttpContext.Response.Body)`. It will work as long as the writing of the stream is forward only (no rewinding, because you are in most cases directly writing to the wire/TCP connection to the users browser) and the (unofficial at least) EPPlus package does have that constructor (see source [here](https://github.com/VahidN/EPPlus.Core/blob/master/src/EPPlus.Core/ExcelPackage.cs#L328)) and you likely have to call  `Save()` method

Comment: Or just do `excel.SaveAs(HttpContext.Response.Body)` w/o the `MemoryStream` in the first place. Why waste memory when you can directly write to the response stream... You'll just must understand previous solutions to your problems and apply them in the future, not ask for a copy & paste ready code every single time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return one of [FileStreamResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_File_System_IO_Stream_System_String_System_String_) in Controller action.

It returns a file in the specified fileStream with the specified contentType as the Content-Type and the specified fileDownloadName as the suggested file name.

```
public virtual FileStreamResult File(Stream fileStream, string contentType, string fileDownloadName)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Sample action method-

```
var data = new[]{
                        new{ Name="Ram", Email="ram@techbrij.com", Phone="111-222-3333" },
                        new{ Name="Shyam", Email="shyam@techbrij.com", Phone="159-222-1596" },
                        new{ Name="Mohan", Email="mohan@techbrij.com", Phone="456-222-4569" },
                        new{ Name="Sohan", Email="sohan@techbrij.com", Phone="789-456-3333" },
                        new{ Name="Karan", Email="karan@techbrij.com", Phone="111-222-1234" },
                        new{ Name="Brij", Email="brij@techbrij.com", Phone="111-222-3333" }
                };

            ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage();
            var workSheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
            workSheet.Cells[1, 1].LoadFromCollection(data, true);

            //var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(excel.GetAsByteArray());

            //Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            //Response.Headers.Add("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=Contact.xlsx");
            //excel.SaveAs(memoryStream);
            //memoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
            //Response.Flush();
            //Response.End();

            return File(excel.GetAsByteArray(), "application/vnd.ms-excel", "Contact.xlsx");
```

Generated Excel screenshot-

[image]

Comment: With your suggestion, it gives the error: `Cannot access a closed Stream`. That is probably because of `Using{...}` statement that closes the stream at the end. But after I removed the `Using{...}` it now downloads an Excel file with no data. I had replaced the last 3 lines with `return File(memoryStream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "Contact.xlsx");`

Comment: Try this - `new MemoryStream(excel.GetAsByteArray());`

Comment: I used `var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(excel.GetAsByteArray());` then got the error at line `excel.SaveAs(memoryStream);`: **Cannot access a closed Stream**.

Comment: You don't have to call `.SaveAs` bcoz `.GetAsByteArray` does that internally.

Comment: I may not be testing the way you are expecting me to test. It seems it working on your side. Could you please copy/paste my code and modify it based on the discussion we have so far? I'll try and let you know if it worked.

Comment: @Sunket It worked. Thank you for taking your time to help others. I noticed you're using `application/vnd.ms-excel` instead of `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`. Do you happen to know a difference b/w the two?